# JavaScript - textarea, Split every line strings after every hash into an array.

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get all lines on the 'textarea' then split every one of them into an array; For Example: I have 3 lines on the textarea like this:

```
#first name #id #mark
#second name #id #mark
#third name #id #mark
```

so I need to split the line's text after every hash'#' into a private array, also with all lines.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: You want all elements inside one array, right? But what do you mean with 'all lines'?

Comment: Yes, I mean doing the same process with every line.

Comment: @j08691 Sorry, I'm new on the community and thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could address the textarea with an `id` and split the string for lines and items.

```js
var content = document.getElementById('area').value,
    result = content.split('\n').map(function (a) {
        return a.split(/\s?#/).slice(1);
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<textarea id="area">#first name #id #mark
#second name #id #mark
#third name #id #mark</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what i need :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like I was too slow, but anyways, here you go.

```js
var data = document.getElementById('txt').value.split('\n'),
    solution = data.map(v => v.replace(/^#|\s(?=#)/g, '').split('#'));

console.log(solution);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<textarea cols='30' rows='10' id='txt'>#first name #id #mark
#second name #id #mark
#third name #id #mark</textarea>
```

Comment: Thank's for your help :)

Comment: @medomedo It's one line vs three lines of Nina's solution. Consider changing your best answer (:

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var txt = $(selector).val();
var txtArray = txt.split('\n').map(function(line){
    line = line.trim();
    return line.split('#').map(function(itemHash){
        return itemHash.trim();
    }).filter(function(itemHash){
        return itemHash != "" 
    });
}).filter(function(line){
    return line != "" 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/idkc/e3r79wm4/